# How to use CSS3 Patterns?

Tags: html, css

How can i use these patterns?
http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#japanese-cube

Here is my failed attempt.
http://jsfiddle.net/ujmWH/

Tried in tinkerbin too, same result.

Thanks

Comment: You should always include the relevant code within your question.  Links are helpful but they should be in addition to the code within the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add specific vendor prefixes, because that CSS3 properties are not standard yet. You can google that topic to know about reasons.

Add `-moz-` to `linear-grandient` function, and you have (in Firefox):

> http://jsfiddle.net/ujmWH/1/

You should add also `-webkit-` (for Chrome and Safari) and `-o-` (for Opera).

So, the complete CSS will be:

```
body {
    background-color:#556;
    background-image: 
        -moz-linear-gradient(60deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
        -moz-linear-gradient(-60deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
        -moz-linear-gradient(60deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
        -moz-linear-gradient(-60deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
        -moz-linear-gradient(30deg, #99a 25%, transparent 25.5%, transparent 75%, #99a 75%, #99a),
        -moz-linear-gradient(30deg, #99a 25%, transparent 25.5%, transparent 75%, #99a 75%, #99a);
    background-image:
        -webkit-linear-gradient(60deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(-60deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(60deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(-60deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, #99a 25%, transparent 25.5%, transparent 75%, #99a 75%, #99a),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, #99a 25%, transparent 25.5%, transparent 75%, #99a 75%, #99a);
    background-image: 
        -o-linear-gradient(60deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
        -o-linear-gradient(-60deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
        -o-linear-gradient(60deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
        -o-linear-gradient(-60deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
        -o-linear-gradient(30deg, #99a 25%, transparent 25.5%, transparent 75%, #99a 75%, #99a),
        -o-linear-gradient(30deg, #99a 25%, transparent 25.5%, transparent 75%, #99a 75%, #99a);
    background-image: 
        linear-gradient(60deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
        linear-gradient(-60deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
        linear-gradient(60deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
        linear-gradient(-60deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
        linear-gradient(30deg, #99a 25%, transparent 25.5%, transparent 75%, #99a 75%, #99a),
        linear-gradient(30deg, #99a 25%, transparent 25.5%, transparent 75%, #99a 75%, #99a);
    background-size: 80px 140px;
    background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 40px 70px, 40px 70px, 0 0, 40px 70px;
}
```

Comment: And then I told myself: it's worth it? Using a GIF will be also lighter (in bytes)...

Answer (score 3):

You have to either add all the prefixes, as lorenzo-s pointed out, or use -prefix-free: http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/ (but read the limitations first)